Exporting Chrome's extensions page as PDF/HTML/Image/anything
I've no clue how to export chrome://extensions/ as anything.
Would be great to get a PDF, but no, Google exports only the first page.
Maybe screenshotting it? Nope, doesn't work.
Maybe use the DevTools? Nope, you cannot copy the HTML tree, it's so dynamic, most of the page's code is not there.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't know what to "clarify". I need to export this chrome web page/address that spans multiple pages. Nothing works.

This is a programming site. Try superuser.com or a Google forum.

@EML Do you really believe normal users can do something programmers cannot?? This is a very non-trivial problem and so far I've come up only with stitching screenshots which is terribly inconvenient, error-prone and time consuming.
